# Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() In magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

i am trying to Create a Custom module ( A Copy Paste From Definitive Guide ) to Show random Products on the Home Page. I Started With Hello world It was Fine. But when I added More Code to Show Products On Home Page It Is Giving Me The Following Error.

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Definitivehello/Block/Randomproducts.php on line 12`

here goes my code for `/app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Definitivehello/Block/Randomproducts.php`

```
<?php
class Magentotutorial_Definitivehello_Block_Randomproducts 
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $randProdModel = Mage::getModel('Magentotutorial_Definitivehello/Randomproducts');
        $randProducts = $randProdModel->getRandomProducts();
        $html = "<ul>";
        foreach ($randProducts as $product) {
            $name = $product->getName();
            $price = number_format($product->getPrice(), 2);
            $imageLink = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(100,100);
            $productLink = $this->helper('catalog/product')->getProductUrl($product);
            $html .= "<p><a href='$productLink'><img src='$imageLink' alt='$name'/></a><br/> $name <br/> $price </p>";
        }
        $html .= "<ul>";
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Can anyone Tell Me Whats Wrong. Thanks

Here Goes My Code For GetRandomProducts() method

```
<?php
class Magentotutorial_Definitivehello_Model_Randomproducts 
    extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function getRandomProducts($maxCount = 3)
    {
        $randProducts = array();
        $allProducts = array();
        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->getItems();

        foreach ($productCollection as $id => $data) {
            //print_r($data); exit;
            $allProducts[] = $data;
        }

        $productIds = array_keys($allProducts);
        $totalProductIds = count($productIds);
        for ($i=0; $i<$maxCount; $i++) {
            $randIndex = rand(0,$totalProductIds);
            $randProductId = $productIds[$randIndex];
            $randProducts[] = $allProducts[$randProductId];
        }
        return $randProducts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Crystal ball is broken. Upload code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `getRandomProducts` of `Magentotutorial_Definitivehello/Randomproducts` model does not return a product collection.

UPD:

Here is a simplier implementation of the getRandomProduct method:

```
<?php
public function getRandomProducts($maxCount = 3)
{
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()')->limit($maxCount);

    return $productCollection;
}
```

Comment: Yes, You are right, But u know it sometimes work and some times it doesn't.. May I know what is The cause that Sometimes getRandomProducts() returns a product collection and Sometimes Not.

Comment: Coud you show the code behind the model Magentotutorial_Definitivehello/Randomproducts and the method getRandomProducts?